# Can't install Laravelcollective/HTML in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravelcollective

I have problem when install Laravelcollective/HTML in Laravel 5.1 [Install laravelcollective/html document](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html).
First, I install through Composer:

```
composer require illuminate/html
```

Message: 
`Using version ~5.0 for illuminate/html
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)`

But it's version 5.0 so remove it.

```
composer remove illuminate/html
```

And install version 5.1

```
"require": {
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"
}
```

Next, update Composer from the Terminal:

```
composer update
```

Next, add your new provider to the providers array of config/app.php:

```
  'providers' => [
    // ...
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

Finally, add two class aliases to the aliases array of config/app.php:

```
  'aliases' => [
    // ...
      'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
      'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

And message error:

```
 FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 146:
 Class 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before I ran composer update, I had somehow added to config/app.php the below and thus it generated the same error you were getting.

Don't add the below until after doing the composer update.

```
'providers' => [
    // ...
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    // ...
  ],

  'aliases' => [
    // ...
      'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
      'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution. You can run this command below by composer. It will install `laravelcollective/html`

```
composer require laravelcollective/html
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I had a cached config file, I could not re-cache it since it gets cached via artisan and artisan was throwing the error.

Solution:

Removed:

```
bootstrap/cache/config.php

composer update
```